# Storybook full text search

Tags: storybook

Our react project uses Storybook v7. Now the search is possible in the navigation tree by the name of the components. Is it possible to implement keyword search for component descriptions or their properties in Storybook auto documentation. Let's say the description includes the following text "The component used to select products from the category ". I would like to be able to search by this description as well, not just the name of the component or the history in the tree. Thanks

I tried @toptal/davinci-storybook-full-text-search-addon, but for some reason it didn't work